# FindFit or Integration Making Use of NumericQ Not Converging

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting

Hello Mathematica Users,

I'm using ?NumericQ to solve an integral numerically and then fit the data to give me values for certain parameters.

The integrals involved appear in:

$$
\alpha  = \frac{\int_{0}^{r_{csda}} \rho\times e^{\mu\rho-\frac{2r_g}{\lambda}sin^{-1}(\rho/2r_g)}d\rho}{\int_{0}^{r_{csda}} \rho\times e^{\mu\rho-\rho/\lambda}d\rho} 
$$

where $r_g = \frac{p}{qB}$. In all this, $\alpha$ is the dependent variable, $B$ is the independent variable and the parameters I need to fit for are $\lambda$ and $r_{csda}$.

The numerator can't be solved analytically and so I have written the following Mathematica code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
E0 := 10                                                   
(* \
Electron energy in MeV*)
(*St :=2.149;                (* 10 MeV 
Stopping power in water MeV/cm*)*)
r0 := 4.975 ;                                   
(* 10 MeV csda range \
in water cm*)
mc2 := 0.51099895 ;                      
(* Electron mass*c2 MeV*)
q := 3 ;                                                
(* Electron \
Charge compatible with units of Mev, 
cm and teslas *)
mu = 0.0157948384752221;                                                
(*attenuation constant*)

Zf[l_, csda_] = l*(l + (-csda + 
    l*(-1 + mu*csda)*Exp[(mu - 1/l)*csda])/((-1 + l*mu)^2));

rg[B_] = E0/q*B; 

NZfprime[l_, rho_, B_] = rho*Exp[mu*rho - (2*rg[B]/l)*ArcSin[rho/(2*rg[B])]];

alpha[l_?NumericQ, csda_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[NZfprime[l, rho, B], {rho, 0, csda}]/Zf[l, csda];

data = {{0, 1}, {0.3, 0.999552770379519}, {0.4, 
0.998805851062253}, {0.5, 0.998066565041057}, {0.6, 
0.997060919995234}};

solution1 = FindFit[data, {alpha[l,csda, B], l > 0, 
csda < 10}, {{l, 0.000001}, {csda, 2}}, {B}]

Show[Plot[solution1[x], {x, 0.1, 1}], ListPlot[data]]
```

The first problem is the data point {0,1}. Using my code, Mathematica doesn't recognise that when $B=0$, $\alpha =1$. However, when I eliminate that data point, Mathematica still has problems, probably because $\lambda$ is very small. I keep getting the following error messages:

```
NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option. >>    
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::izero will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

and

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in rho near {rho} = {1.789}. NIntegrate obtained -1.63470314044198918853761342200621303622880363340610336427127743697*10^-3960980+2.57268143657927767936334415959354139897206405201367090837780304657*10^-3960981 I and 8.5838860214619239726652239787055605419565681362037772502604174771`65.954589770191*^-3960980 for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

I'm only an occasional user of Mathematica and so do not have a really clear idea of what these error messages are prompting me to do. Does anybody have any solutions/insights?

Thanks in advance, 
                  RL

Comment: `ArcSin`-argument `rho/(2*rg[B])==(3 rho)/(20 B)`   is singular for `B==0` ? In this case ArcSin isn't real!

Comment: I see that `ArcSin`-argument `rho/(2*rg[B])==(3 rho)/(20 B)` is singular for `B==0`. However the point that Mathematica fails to notice is that the full term `(2*rg[B]/l)*ArcSin[rho/(2*rg[B])` is not singular for `B==0`; instead it converges to `rho/l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With corrected variable assignments

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
E0 = 10(*Electron energy in MeV*)
(*St:=2.149;(*10 MeV Stopping power in water MeV/cm*)*)
r0 = 4.975;
(*10 MeV csda range in water cm*)
mc2 = 0.51099895;
(*Electron mass*c2 MeV*)
q = 3;
(*Electron Charge compatible with units of Mev,cm and teslas*)
mu = 0.0157948384752221;
(*attenuation constant*)

Zf[l_, csda_] :=l*(l + (-csda +l*(-1 + mu*csda)*Exp[(mu - 1/l)*csda])/((-1 +l*mu)^2));
rg[B_] := E0/q*B;
```

and **changed argument inside ArcSin**

```
NZfprime[l_, rho_, B_] :=rho*Exp[mu*rho - (2*rg[B]/l)*ArcSin[rho/(2)*(rg[B])]];

alpha[l_?NumericQ, csda_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[NZfprime[l, rho, B], {rho, 0, csda}]/Zf[l, csda];

data = {{0, 1}, {0.3, 0.999552770379519}, {0.4,0.998805851062253}, {0.5, 0.998066565041057}, {0.6,0.997060919995234}};
```

the fit evaluates an optimum

```
FindFit[data, {alpha[l, csda, B](*,l>0,csda<10*)}, {l, csda}, B,Method -> "NMinimize"]
(*{csda -> 0.162831, l -> 0.934341}*)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich, for taking the time to correct my code. However, there are still a few issues. As I pointed out in the above comment, your change to the argument of `ArcSin` is leads to a function different from the original, correct one. `(2*rg[B]/l)*ArcSin[rho/(2*rg[B])` does indeed converge to `rho/l` though at the moment Mathematica does not realize it. How can I correct my code so that Mathematica can deal with what is only apparently a singularity?

Comment: What a pity. I tried to substitute the intgration variable `rho->rho B` but the singlarity still remains. Just an observation: If I minimize `Rest[data]` I get a very poor fit of the data? Are you sure about the model?

Comment: ..The integrand `NZfprime[l, rho, B]` is only real for `B==0` ! Though you try to fit a complex modell to real data?

Comment: My understanding is that `ArcSin[x]` will be real as long as `-1<x<1` . In the present case it will be real for all values of `rho<2*rg[B]`. Unless there is a mistake that I haven't seen, I believe the integrand should be real.

Comment: I agree,   `rho<20/3 B` implies the restriction `csda<20/3B`

Comment: I checked the model again and there is a mistake in `Zf[l_, csda_]`. It should read `Zf[l_, csda_] := 
 l*(l + ((-csda + l*(-1 + mu*csda))*Exp[(mu - 1/l)*csda]))/((-1 + 
       l*mu)^2)`. I think now the remaining problem is dealing with the data point {0,1}. This should be feasible since it is a removable singularity.

Comment: You should consider the restriction `rho<2*rg[B]` (Is it correct?) inside `Fit`.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment above, there was a slight error in the code. I also found a way to deal with the removable singularity. Many thanks to Ulrich for guiding and spurring me on.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
E0 = 10(*Electron energy in MeV*)
(*St:=2.149;(*10 MeV Stopping power in water MeV/cm*)*)
r0 = 4.975;
(*10 MeV csda range in water cm*)
mc2 = 0.51099895;
(*Electron mass*c2 MeV*)
q = 3;
(*Electron Charge compatible with units of Mev,cm and teslas*)
mu = 0.0157948384752221;
(*attenuation constant*)

Zf[l_, csda_] :=l*(l + ((-csda +l*(-1 + mu*csda))*Exp[(mu - 1/l)*csda])/((-1 
+l*mu)^2));
arc[B_,rho_,l_] := (2*E0/(q*B*l))*ArcSin[rho/(2*E0/(q*B))];
NZfprime[l_, rho_, B_] :=rho*Exp[mu*rho - arc[B,rho,l]];
limit=rho*Exp[mu*rho - rho/l]; 

alpha[l_?NumericQ,csda_?NumericQ,B_?NumericQ]:= 
NIntegrate[If[B==0,limit,NZfprime[l, rho, B]],
{rho,0,csda},Method{"GlobalAdaptive",Method"MultipanelRule"}]/Zf[l,csda];

data = {{0, 1}, {0.3, 0.999552770379519}, {0.4,0.998805851062253}, {0.5, 
0.998066565041057}, {0.6,0.997060919995234}};

FindFit[data, {alpha[l, csda, B](*,l>0,csda<10*)}, {l, csda}, B,Method -> 
"NMinimize"]
```